# How to join tables with more than one attribute match?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to turn my raw sql into laravel query builder and I encounter difficulty on how to join multiple tables using with many attributes match.

In this case, I want to join the table jr_h and jr_d with three attributes match (book,p_seq and staff_code) rather than one (book).
Raw sql:

```
 $sql =  "select from_time,to_time,t.staff_code,s.name_t as staff_name,t.book,t.p_code,t.p_seq,p.hrs1,s.img_file, 
        t.hrs_work,p.sharing_cnt  as hrs_work, t.hrs_ot  as hrs_ot from jr_d as t 
        inner join jr_h as p on(t.book=p.book and t.p_seq=p.p_seq and t.staff_code=p.staff_code)  
        inner join astaff as s on(t.staff_code=s.staff_code) ";
```

Laravel query builder:

```
   $jr_d = DB::table('jr_d')
        ->join('jr_h', 'jr_d.book', '=', 'jr_h.book')
        ->join('astaff', 'jr_d.staff_code', '=', 'astaff.staff_code')
        ->select('jr_h.*','jr_d.*','astaff.*','astaff.name_t as staff_name')
        ->where('jr_d.ref_group','=','E')
        ->get();
```

and also want to know if there is a way to make the query faster since it has a lot of data in the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel joins with multiple conditions:

```
$results = DB::table('jr_d')
            ->select('jr_h.*','jr_d.*','astaff.*','astaff.name_t as staff_name')
            ->join('jr_h', 'jr_d.book', '=', 'jr_h.book')
            ->join('jr_h as p', function($query){
                $query->on('t.book','=', p.book');
                $query->on('t.p_seq','=', 'p.p_seq');
                $query->on('t.staff_code', '=', 'p.staff_code');
            })
            ->where('jr_d.ref_group','=','E')
            ->get();
    `
```

Comment: yes it works, how to make it faster? i am waiting 3mins for it to work...

Comment: @QiYang then please accept the answer, in general the query is nearly raw sql statement and you really dont have much options on how to make it faster, as multiple joins with multiple conditions are slowing it down. A suggestion to make it faster is to add indexing to the tables that you are joining.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
// ...
->join('jr_h p', function($join) {
   $join->on('t.book', '=', 'p.book');
   $join->on('t.p_seq', '=', 'p.p_seq');
// ... more conditions
});
```

Comment: yes it works, how to make it faster? i am waiting 3mins for it to work...

Comment: Well, the performance is probably not related to the query written in Laravel DB builder. You might need to define indexes on different columns if not already there.

Comment: I query a lot based on the date, that means I should define index on the date column for most of the tables?

Comment: Define an index on the date column can improve its performance

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$jr_d = DB::table('jr_d')
        ->join('jr_h', 'jr_d.book', '=', 'jr_h.book')
        ->join('astaff', 'jr_d.staff_code', '=', 'astaff.staff_code')
        ->select('*','astaff.name_t as staff_name')
        ->where('jr_d.ref_group','=','E')
        ->get();
```